# How can I stop a game object box collider triggering underneath a dropdown box UI element?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dropdown, unity-ui

How can I stop a game object box collider triggering underneath a dropdown box UI element?

When I select a dropdown list item, it also sends a click through to the game object beneath the dropdown list.

Obviously we only want one UI element getting clicked in this case.

[image]

Comment: Use a different _layer?_

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I just tried that, it still hits them both. 
Dropdown is on the UI layer, Game Object on the default layer.

Comment: Rats...well it was worth a try. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems there is no "inbuilt" or elegant way to do this, so its workaround time:
Here is what I came up with that works perfectly.

Put these two lines in your update () to set a boolean flag marking the drop box in use.

```
  if (MyDropBox.transform.childCount != 3 && !MyDropBoxDown) { MyDropBoxDown   =  true;}    // Detect dropbox down and set a bool flag
  if (MyDropBox.transform.childCount == 3 && MyDropBoxDown)  { MyDropBoxDown   =  false;}   // detect dropbox up and unset a bool flag
```

Then you can either disable the box collider usng this flag, or just drop out of the function called by the box collider, eg if (MyDropBoxDown) {return} so it doesn't run.

Comment: Im happy you got a solution!! but seems it can bring more problems in the future haha, search for examples for my solution and I am sure you will love it. (Not now but it will help someday)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is implement `IPointerClick` on the scripts attached (a series of these interfaces are located in `UnityEngine.EventsSystems`) on both UI and the box collider, using this both will use the same event system and it will be effectively blocked.

You will need to add a `PhysicsRaycaster` to the main camera.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I was hoping there was a "don't pass clicks through" option in the UI, but it seems not. I didn't really understand your workaround, but I did knock up a workaround myself.